# Using NULL keys in Rails I18n locales

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization, rails-i18n

I use rails-i18n (5.1.3) gem and I wonder how to get the value from the NULL key in the `yml` file:

```
---
en:
  block:
    ~: 'Block' # `~` and `null` keys work the same way
    user: 'Block user'
    admin: 'Block admin'
```

I tried:

```rb
pry(main)> I18n.t('block')
=> {nil=>"Block", :user=>"Block user", :admin=> "Block admin"}
pry(main)> I18n.t('block.')
=> {nil=>"Block", :user=>"Block user", :admin=> "Block admin"}
pry(main)> I18n.t('block.null')
=> "translation missing: en.block.null"
pry(main)> I18n.t('block.nil')
=> "translation missing: en.block.nil"
pry(main)> I18n.t('block.~')
=> "translation missing: en.block.~"
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a good reason why you're using `null` for a key here? Could you use use something else, like `other` or `default`?

I've never seen this in a translation file before - and after a little research, it seems to be [explicitly disabled](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/pull/236) by the library. In fact, the default `I18n` back-end [explicitly handles `nil` keys by returning `nil`](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/blob/04a814bab173d495c44fe683309aaff18a42593e/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L30-L34).

If you feel this is a valid use case, you could try writing your own back-end that handles `nil` as desired (perhaps with `I18n.t('block.~')` or `I18n.t('block.null')`) -- and if it's successful, open a PR to the library.

Or as a quick workaround, you could use: `I18n.t('block').fetch(nil)`.

...Or, as I said originally, you could just use a different key; like `other`.